# Spline Vanilla JS in Flutter WebViewX Plus

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, webview

I have a Flutter application (Web), where I am initializing a

```dart
late WebViewXController webviewController;
```

I have created a function that loads a Spline 3D design, exported as Vanilla JS (Web Content) zip file that I extracted in my assets. This function loads the HTML and JS files.

```dart
Future<void> loadHtmlFromAsset(controller) async {
  const htmlPath = '3ddesign/index.html';
  final htmlContent = await rootBundle.loadString(htmlPath);
  controller.loadContent(
    htmlContent,
    fromAssets: true, 
    sourceType: SourceType.html,
  );
}
```

This function is called in a `WebViewX` widget from the webviewx_plus library, and once the controller is initiated, the load asset function above is called:

```dart
WebViewX(
  height: Get.size.height * 0.50,
  width: Get.size.width * 0.50,
  initialContent: "Loading...",
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
    webviewController = controller;
    controller.evalRawJavascript(
      'document.querySelector("iframe").sandbox = "allow-same-origin";',
    );
    loadHtmlFromAsset();
  },
),
```

Now I have worked this around for a while now, getting errors such as connector not initialized and sandbox will be escaped, etc.

**What is the correct way to integrate my web assets (html and js files) into a Flutter widget?**